# How can I localize a standard iOS control?

Tags: ios, uitableview, localization

I'm writing an iPhone app that has a table cell with the style UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete.  This causes the cell to be displayed with a red circle enclosing a minus sign on the left side.  Fine so far.  It also has a Delete button (rectangular button with the text "Delete") on the right side.  I need to change the text "Delete" for localization to other languages.  Where is this text defined?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should take a look at the following method in the `UITableViewDelegate Protocol`:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

See the [**docs**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:).

Comment: Genius! I looked for quite a while - how did you know where to find that?