# Custom Expandable Table View Delete Button Text

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am using this custom table view [Here](https://github.com/wannabegeek/ExpandableTableView)

I want to localize "Delete" button text which reveals when swiped left but could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857159/how-can-i-localize-a-standard-ios-control

Comment: @ErsinSezgin That delegate method never gets called for me even though I set `self.tableView.delegate = self`

Comment: Use storyboard to attach your delegate to your controller. Make sure self.tableview is your tableview!

Comment: @ErsinSezgin [Here](https://github.com/okhanokbay/deleteButtonTextTrial) is my project and I cant still handle it.Could you please check it?

Comment: Add `titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:` method to `ExpandableTableView.m` **not your** `ExampleController.m`, because ExpandableTableView handles UITableViewDelegate methods for your tableview, since `ExpandableTableView` defines its own delegates by appending `UITableViewDelegate` methods.

Comment: @ErsinSezgin Thank you so much.It worked and clarified the whole situation for me.

Comment: No problem, I am just copy-pasting the solution and I will create an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:` method to `ExpandableTableView.m` not your `ExampleController.m`, because `ExpandableTableView` handles `UITableViewDelegate` methods for your tableview, since `ExpandableTableView` defines its own delegates by appending `UITableViewDelegate` methods.